# ATG runAssembler - order of modules import

Tags: e-commerce, atg

I'm trying to create ear with ATG runAssembler based on default commerce reference store and my main purpose is to override some jsp files of CRS.

I've created module MyModule (with submodule Storefront which contains my war file) and specified in Manifest all the required modules including Store.Storefront. For my opinion MyModule.Storefront should be the last one in runAssembler's imports, cause first all the required modules should be imported. I used the following command to create ear:

```
./runAssembler -overwrite -standalone $DYNAMO_ROOT/MyModule/deploy/MyModule.ear -m MyModule.Storefront
```

But I got the wrong order of imports:

```
...
Importing classes...
Importing classes for module DafEar
Importing classes for module MyModule.Storefront
Importing classes for module DafEar.Admin
Importing classes for module DafEar.base
Importing classes for module DCS.PublishingAgent
Importing classes for module Store.Storefront
Importing classes for module DCS.AbandonedOrderServices
...
```

What have I made wrong? What do I have to do to change the order? Do you know any other way to override CRS jsp pages not affecting the default files?

Thank you.

UPD:
MANIFEST of MyModule.Storefront:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.0
ATG-Version: 10.1.2
ATG-Version-Full: 10.1.2
ATG-Config-Path: config/
ATG-Product: STF
ATG-Required: MyModule.Back Store.Storefront
ATG-Web-Module: j2ee-apps/Storefront/store.war
```

Comment: What does your MANIFEST.MF file look like for MyModule.Storefront? Your custom module should depend on Store.Storefront so it will get built after ATG module. Also in runAssembler, move MyModule.Storefront after Store.Storefront.

Comment: I've added the requested Manifest to the description. The problem is that I've made many experiences with different orders of modules in the manifest and runAssembler, but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the module `Store.Storefront` to the begining of the field `ATG-Required`: the Nucleus orders the required modules with their position on this field.

Comment: I found the decision: I've put my module to the end of the list in runAssembler modules and have removed ATG-Required from manifest of my module.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using layering concept of ATG then you should know that we override the properties of the existing properties for that particular component. This is not define to override the JSP pages.
If you want to replace CRS JSP with custom JSP then you need to change the component(.properties files in config folder) value.

Comment: As far as I know JSPs are not defined as Nucleus components so it's impossible to override JSP overriding the appropriate property. Am I right? Maybe I misunderstood you.